# How to refresh a inline VF page when we create record from quick action in lightning?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, quickaction

I have created a VF page to show related contacts with more functionality and added in account detail page.

Now when I try to create a contact using quick action on Account object. My Visualforce page doesn't refresh except my visualforce page everything else in UI get refreshed.

How to refresh my VF page when creating the record from the quick action?

Currently I thinking to use action:poller to refresh after particular time or using streaming api/plantform event in VF page. other than any solution?

Comment: is that standard quick action?

Comment: @kurunve yes standard quick action